# Apache CXF + JavaFX No conduit initiator was found for the namespace

Tags: apache, javafx, cxf

I'm triying to run a JavaFX Rest client using CXF. A very simple test. When I try to get an URL I get the org.apache.cxf.BusException: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http. I took a look at some related questions here, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.
Then only maven dependency I added was cxf-rt-rs-client 3.1.0
The code is:

`WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
         client.type("text/html").accept("text/html");
         System.out.println(client.get());`

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.
at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl.getConduitInitiator(ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl.java:110)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.selectConduit(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.message.ExchangeImpl.getConduit(ExchangeImpl.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.getConduit(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:71)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:624)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 7):

The shading overwrites bus-extension.txt file. Programmatically your can fix it by initializing it.

```
void initializeCxf() {
    final Bus defaultBus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();
    final ConduitInitiatorManager extension = defaultBus.getExtension(ConduitInitiatorManager.class);
    extension.registerConduitInitiator("http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http", new HTTPTransportFactory());
}
```

Based on the comment by @hba you can also try following in case the above does not work

```
extension.registerConduitInitiator("http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http", new HTTPTransportFactory(defaultBus));
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me described here.  I upvoted it because it is essentially  correct.  I had to do the following: extension.registerConduitInitiator("http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http",
                                           new HTTPTransportFactory(defaultBus))

Answer (score 0):

You are fine with your Maven dependencies.

Client construction looks a bit *off* per CXF 3.x guides, wherein JAX-RS 2.0 is supported.

See [AX-RS 2.0 Client API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-JAX-RS2.0ClientAPI).

Try this code:

```
    WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://stackoverflow.com/");

    Response response = target.request().get();
    System.out.println(response.getEntity().getClass().getName());
```

Using this code, you will learn the response entity is an input stream .. a sequence of characters being the HTML content of the StackOverflow home page.

If you're feeling adventurous, and to demonstrate I'm not a charlatan, add the following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and then attempt this:

```
    WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString((InputStream) target.request().get().getEntity(), "UTF-8"));
```

You will be rewarded with a textual rendering (on standard output) of the StackOverflow home page – equivalent to performing a "view source" operation in your browser.

I don't know what your ultimate goal is, but if you're attempting to build anything useful from information on the StackExchange network, I suggest use of their APIs documented [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help David, but the code you've suggested does not work either (same exception), but I created a simple Java SE application with maven, then added the same code to the main function and it worked. I believe the problem it's something related to CXF and JavaFX interaction, but still no luck to find out the cause.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that is curious. At the moment I can't think of what in JavaFX might be interfering.

Comment: Maybe something related with classpath. I'll try to find it out and post the cause. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception when using Apache CXF REST client in JavaFX project. The code is below:

```
MyClass rest = (MyClass) JAXRSClientFactory.create(endpoint, MyClass.class, Collections.singletonList(new JacksonJsonProvider()));
System.out.println("Service health: " + rest.health());
```

A test with plain Java project works fine with the same code and same dependencies. It is apparently a conflict between JavaFX and Apache CXF. I am trying to figure out why.

If you guys already solved this issue, that should be great to update this thread, which is the only result on Google search.

Updated solution:
After a while, I found that the default Maven project does not include enough the dependencies in the plugin "maven-dependency-plugin". I tried to add more packages in the list but still not work. So the final solution is in this thread: [How to package an Apache CXF application into a monolithic JAR with the Maven "shade" plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831954/how-to-package-an-apache-cxf-application-into-a-monolithic-jar-with-the-maven-s). Shade plugin is much better and works.