# Camel: how do Type Converters load?

Tags: maven, apache-camel, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

When run my application through `mvn compile exec:java` it says:

```
[main] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 199 type converters
```

When run through `java -jar` (uberjar made with `maven-shade-plugin`) it says:

```
[main] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 182 type converters
```

Check the difference (199 over 182). As the result my code does not work as expected in some cases.

Using camel `2.16.1`. If full list of dependencies needed, let me know, I'll put with update.

**UPDATE 1**
Solved by adding

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter</resource>
</transformer>
```

to my `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.

Comment: Type Converters are discovered via the [Service Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism. Could you please post the configuration of the `maven-shade-plugin` and the output of `mvn dependency:tree` so I can analyse? My suspicion is that some Camel dependency is not being packaged, e.g. `runtime` or `provided` dependencies.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-a-big-uber-jar.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter</resource>
</transformer>
```

to my `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.

More details here: [How to package an Apache CXF application into a monolithic JAR with the Maven "shade" plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831954/how-to-package-an-apache-cxf-application-into-a-monolithic-jar-with-the-maven-s)